# Are iCE5LP1K, iCE5LP2K and iCE5LP4K FPGAs actually the same device?

Tags: fpga, reverse-engineering, lattice

In [official datasheet](https://www.latticesemi.com/%7E/media/LatticeSemi/Documents/DataSheets/iCE/iCE40UltraFamilyDataSheet.pdf), iCE5LP1K has less logic elements than the larger models:

[image: Screenshot from ICE5LP datasheet]

However, the iCEcube2 tool shows them all to consist of 20x24 array of logic blocks, each having 8 logic elements. This gives a total of 3520 logic elements, matching the largest iCE5LP4K.

The software allows free placement of cells within the array even for smaller devices. The software refuses to write output if the total amount of logic cells exceeds the value listed in the table.

**Are these devices actually all the same die? Can same bitstream be used on all devices?**

Comment: Rather than make three separate product lines, it is easier and cheaper to make one, then "program" or "fuse" certain features on/off.  Increases yield also; one cell malfunction means just that physical section can be disabled and the device rebranded as a smaller model.  The rareness of the full-capability model can drive its price upwards, compared to the (then) abundance of smaller variants.

Comment: @rdtsc Yeah, I have seen in microcontrollers that often there is more memory capacity than advertised. First time I see it in FPGAs though. I think that the low-level nature of FPGAs would make it difficult to disable malfunctioning areas, considering the tool appears to allow free routing in the whole matrix. So I think these are probably fully functional devices just sold at different prices.

Answer (score 1):

Getting a definite answer would require decapping the IC and comparing.

But based on experimental results, I would say: **yes, they are the same device**.

Bitstream generated for iCE5LP4K or iCE5LP2K works correctly on part labeled iCE5LP1K. Because the synthesis tool doesn't apply any constraints to the logic placement, it seems unlikely that these could be partially defective parts. Timing parameters also match between the models.